# how we can simply export a webpage to pdf on click of button using php

Tags: php, html, pdf

I have seen many third party plugins and other sources of converting to pdf but here the question is, but is there any simple way to convert the webpage into pdf and export them without using any third party plugin.

`<input id="convert_pdf" class="form-control btn btn-primary" value="convert(PDF)" >`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Comment: You can use [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/).

Comment: @Sand can u explain in detail how to use it on click of input button

Comment: That you have to learn from that site all the document and help is there. Here is and example [link](http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-in-php-with-fpdf_447.html)